# Shopify Paypal Installment integration - Dynamic pricing

Tags: paypal, shopify, payment-method

non-coder here... Paypal allows me to integrate its 'Pay in 3' messaging on my product pages (Shopify) and can also change the messaging to show the exact (price divided by 3) instalments based on the product price. Am I able to make it calculate this dynamically based on the product price? That would save me having to code each product page separately.

I want *data-pp-amount* to be looking at the product price automatically. I have tried a few html options such as "price" and "price-min, but not sure if it will accept a variable?

Thanks!